# I am not able to retrieve the client secret from stripe to process payment

Tags: reactjs, axios, stripe-payments

```
[The console that shows the out put for the client secret]
```

[emulator terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W1Q6.png)

[emulator log files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieBl5.png)

[hello world out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLMjT.png)
I am following a video tutorial to clone the amazon page and I am having trouble retrieving a client_secret key to process payment further. as you can see in the above capture the console is only showing the initial state value which is "true" but not updating nor generating Client_secret when I add items to the basket and try to process payment, below are what I believe to be relevant parts of the code.

```
I was hoping to get an idea why I am not able to get the Client secret key 
  



import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
    import CheckoutProducts from "./CheckoutProducts";
    import "./Payment.css";
    import { getBasketTotal } from "./Reducer";
    import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
    import axios from "./axios";
    import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    import { db } from "./Firebase";`
    
    function Payment() {
    const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const elements = useElements();
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);
    const Navigate = useNavigate(); 


useEffect(()=>{  
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `/payments/create?total${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
    };
    getClientSecret();
     }, [basket]);
    
    console.log("the secret is>>>", clientSecret);
console.log(getBasketTotal(basket))
    
     const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);
    
    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
    
    
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection("Orders")
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent.amount,
            created: paymentIntent.created,
          });
    
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);
    
        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY__BASKET",
        });
        Navigate("/Orders, { replace: true }");
        // history.replaceState('/orders')
      });
      };



//This is my back end 

  

   const functions = require("firebase-functions");
        const express = require("express");
        const cors = require("cors");
        const stripe = require("stripe")(
      ".... "
        );
     
     const app = express();
       
        app.use(cors({origin:true }));
        
        app.use(express.json());
    
    
        app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello World"));
    
          app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
          const total = request.query.total;
          console.log(
          `payment request recieved BOOHOOOO!!! for this amount >>>`,
             total
         );
        
         const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: total, // subunits of the currency
        currency: "usd",
         });
     
         response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
          });
       });
    
        exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);


import axios from "axios";

const instance=axios.create({

    baseURL:'http://127.0.0.1:5001/cleaver-clone/us-central1/api' // the API (cloud Function) URL
});

export default instance
```

Comment: Can you share the console logs you referenced? Also, have you tried adding log statements to each code block (both front-end and backend) to give you an idea of what parts of your code are running and what parts aren't?

Comment: however from my back end, I am not able to see anything on my terminal, I have consoled to see the "total" which I have parsed from the query in my payment component. so this got me thinking that it could be my back end that has the bug

Comment: I have edited my original post with the information you requested

Comment: Seeing connection refused errors. Are you sure your server is running on port 5001?

Comment: I believe so, I have attached a few screen shots that i believe will show you that

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing the server connectivity out, it made me check the fact that I had a VPN turned on while testing it that has been what has been blocking it this whole time. Thank you very much  that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(({paymentIntent}) => {
            db.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('orders').add({
                paymentIntentId: paymentIntent.id,
                basket: basket,
                amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                created: paymentIntent.created,
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).